# C# How can I make the application receive my input

Tags: c#

I have tried to do a simple Console application in C# where i input a value to get the same amount of stars printed out in console. For example if i input value 5 i console, i would like it to print out 5 stars: *****

1   =>  *

2   =>  **

3   =>  ***

Edit:

```
enter using System;
```

`using System.Collections.Generic;`
`using System.Linq;`
`using System.Text;`
`using System.Threading.Tasks;`
`namespace kvadrat
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)`

```
    {
        Console.Write("Hur stor kvadrat vill du ha? ");
        int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This duplicates what you have. It's unclear in the question what else you need.

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int intValue;
if (int.TryParse(input, out intValue))
{
    Console.WriteLine(new string('*', intValue));
}
```

Comment: I would have guessed the question is more "how can I make the application receive my input" than "how can I change this very specific printing I made"

Comment: Yes i did. And i did not find the answer i was looking for. Im looking for a way where the user can input a number in console and get the same amount of stars  printed out in console.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer of my question.

```
        {
        Console.Write("Hur stor kvadrat vill du ha? ");
        int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    } code here
```